# Can't get text of an XML element in python

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to parse an XML file in python. Here is a small portion of the XML code:

```
<body>
<p feature="XXX">
   <ph>text1 </ph>
      DESIRED TEXT 
   <ph>text2</ph>
   <ph>sometext...</ph>
</p>
</body>
```

I want to get "DESIRED TEXT". I did the following:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(dir)
root = tree.getroot()

for el in root.findall("./body/p"):
    print(el.attrib, el.text)
```

el.attrib return the correct values (which is XXX in this case) but el.text return None.
What am I missing? What should I use instead of .text?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have selected the xpath for the paragraph tag which does not have any inner text, only the child elements like `ph` does have , in that case `el.text` should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xmltodict` lib:

```
import xmltodict

with open('file.xml', 'r') as f:
    result = xmltodict.parse(f.read())['body']['p']['#text']
```

Output:

```
DESIRED TEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

below (no need to install an external library)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<body>
<p feature="XXX">
   <ph>text1 </ph>
      DESIRED TEXT 
   <ph>text2</ph>
   <ph>sometext...</ph>
</p>
</body>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.findall('.//ph')[0].tail.strip())
```